# Column alias name not working in ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to use *alias* name in `ORDER BY` clause. But it gives "column not found". How do I fix this ?

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: It works. Check out this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a860/1

Answer (score 0):

it should work when you use it, something like this works

```
SELECT date_id as id FROM `td_date` ORDER BY id
```

Or use:

```
SELECT date_id,tot
FROM `td_date`
ORDER BY 2
```

in this case it's ordered by 2nd column